# How was Changeling played with cards?

Tags: world-of-darkness, history-of-gaming, changeling-the-dreaming

AFAIK, Changeling 1st edition was played with cards, at least some parts of the game. That was removed from 2nd edition. I think it wasn't very successful, but I'm still very curious about that. Unfortunately, I have never found that edition, and no explanation in any web page (and it would be more difficult now that so many WoD sites are down).

Can someone summarize those card rules?

Comment: Here is the pdf at drivethrurpg.com if you are wanting to read that edition: http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/56/Changeling-the-Dreaming-1st-Edition?term=changeling&it=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cards signify which Art (effect) and Realm (what or whom the effect works on) the character uses. The Player plays these cards. Multiple Realms can be combined, though they cost extra Glamour.

The Player has one Art card "for each dot in Arts" that she or he has. The same goes for Realm dots. The Player also has Bunk cards, in a separate deck, (see below) equal to the total dots in her/his Arts.

The Player also draws a Bunk card (what is required for the Cantrip to work) from a deck of Bunk cards. If the Player cannot or will not fulfill the Bunk, the Cantrip fails. By spending Glamour, the Player can draw two Bunk cards. Both must be fulfilled, but the Player can get more successes.

The Player then describes the effect they wish to achieve. Get creative, judgement is up to the Storyteller.

Depending on the effect, the Player may have to overcome Banality. The Player rolls dice specified by the cards. Art tells the Attribute, Realm the Ability. Target(s) may resist using their own Banality.

Discard, refresh (the latter only after a thorough rest, till then, you always place all the cards except for one you choose into your hand, thus slowly depleting your deck.) The number of cards available are limited by dots etc.

There are "Advanced" complications, such as suits matching resulting in extra successes etc.

Bunks included stuff like tearing a four leaf clover into four separate pieces etc.

Comment: @Jadasc (any of you) I didn't know they were special cards, I thought it were a regular french deck. How was the player's hand formed? Did she receive cards according to her stats in arts and realms, was it random or how?

Comment: @Flamma I've updated/extended my answer with those details, please check them. (The book itself doesn't really go into more detail than that.)

Comment: @Flamma You'd have a hand of Arts and Realms cards that represented the dots you had in those areas, and a random "deck" composed of the Bunks you knew that you'd draw from.

Comment: What about the bunks? If the card says you have to blow leafs at your target, what happens if you don't have leafs on your purses? Can't you cast the cantrip? Or you are automagically able to *have* leafs to throw?

Comment: @Flamma "If you cannot or will not fulfill the bunk, the cantrip fails." Life's tough. :)

Answer (score 8):

The original mechanic for casting cantrips involved the use of collectible [cantrip cards](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/75942/changeling-cantrip-cards), which were available in booster packs.

As for [the system](http://robertdushay.home.mindspring.com/Museum/Horror/Changlingrvw.html):

> Players had a hand of Art and Realm cards, corresponding to what their characters knew, and they selected the cards to use. A Bunk card was drawn at random from the Bunk deck, and if the character executed the Bunk requirement, the cantrip had as many successes as the Bunk card allowed. (Players could spend a point of their character's Glamour to draw a second Bunk card to increase the power of the spell.) After the cantrip was executed, players picked up their cards and discarded one. They could choose to keep their Bunk so they knew the casting requirement for a future cantrip, which meant losing some Art or Realm ability for a session, or they could keep their magical knowledge and discard their Bunk, drawing randomly for the next cantrip.... Players were not allowed to produce the same cantrip using the same bunk.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen And you wrote yours mostly from scratch. +1 to you, too.